# Open popup notification on the same monitor where the mainwindow is in python an pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In my `QMainWindow` i have a button which opens a new `QDialog` in the bottom right monitorcorner with a successmessage when i click it.
Now, if i move the QMainWindow to another monitor (i have 3 monitor) and click the button the successmessage popup appears in the monitor where the `QMainWindow` was opened. What i want is that the popup message appears in the monitor where my QMainWindow actually is. So if i move the `QMainWindow` to Monitor 1 and click the button, the successpopup should opens in monitor 1. If the `QMainWindow` is in monitor 2, the successpopup should open in monitor 2 an same for monitor 3.

with

```
screenNumber = QDesktopWidget().screenNumber(self)
```

i can read the screennumber where the mainwindow is. and this works fine. Evertime i click the button i read out the screennumber. But i don't found a way, to set the screennumber to my notification.
Any ideas?

**Edit:**
maybe it helps if i show my notify class

*notes.py*

```
from UIs.UI_notify import Ui_Notification
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation, QTimer
import sys
class icon():
checked = "check-circle"
alert = "times-circle"
question = "question-circle"

class notify(QDialog, Ui_Notification):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(notify,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        ## Some helping stuff
        ############################################################
        parent_sSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(parent)
        parent_screenNumber = QDesktopWidget().screenNumber(parent)
        sSize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        screenNumber = QDesktopWidget().screenNumber()
        print("notification ScreenNumber = " + str(screenNumber))
        print(sSize.width())
        print(sSize.height())
        print("Parents ScreenNumber = " + str(parent_screenNumber))
        print(parent_sSize.width())
        print(parent_sSize.height())
        self.Note_Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        ## ScreenSize from parent
        ############################################################
        self.hidedPos = QRect(parent_sSize.width()-self.width()-10,
                              parent_sSize.height()-self.height()+200,
                              self.frameGeometry().width(),
                              self.frameGeometry().height())
        self.showPos = QRect(parent_sSize.width()-self.width()-10,
                              parent_sSize.height()-self.height()-50,
                              self.frameGeometry().width(),
                              self.frameGeometry().height())
    
    def setNote(self, icon=icon.checked, headline="Headline", text="Text"):
        self.icon = icon
        self.headline = headline
        self.text = text
        self.noty_Label_Icon.setText(self.icon)
        self.noty_Label_Headline.setText(self.headline)
        self.noty_Label_Text.setText(self.text)
        self.setGeometry(self.hidedPos)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self,b"geometry")
        self.anim.setDuration(700)
        self.anim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutBack)
        self.anim.setEndValue(self.showPos)
        self.anim.start()
        self.notyTimer = QTimer()
        self.notyTimer.singleShot(4000,self.hideNote)
    def hideNote(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self,b"geometry")
        self.anim.setDuration(700)
        self.anim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutBack)
        self.anim.setEndValue(self.hidedPos)
        self.anim.start()
        self.anim.finished.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    notes = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = notify()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(notes.exec())
```

Comment: If the dialog is created with the parent, it *should* open in the center of that parent, wherever it is. Please provide an *actual* [mre] where you open the notify dialog *from* the main window.

Comment: The dialog I not created with the parent. I create it everytime i click the button

Comment: By "with" I mean the *argument*. A QDialog works properly when created with a parent and its shown as modal. All this is *clearly* explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details).

Comment: yes, you are right. i found out that the animation part is the problem. But i dont know how to fix it yet. I will test something out. If have a fast solution for me, please tell me. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the size of the widget during its construction, as at that moment it has a default size (640x480 for top level widgets, 100x30 for widgets created with a parent, including dialogs): the only reliable option is to use the `sizeHint()` or ensure that the layout has been properly activated with `adjustSize()`.

Then, you don't need the screen to get the target position, as the parent geometry will suffice, but you *do* need it for the start position, otherwise the dialog will "pop up" at an arbitrary point *below* the window. Note that QDesktopWidget is considered obsolete, and you should use QScreen instead.

Finally, since you might want to reuse the notification, the start position should be set when the popup is actually being shown, not before. The same goes for the position when hiding (in case the notification could be moved).

```
class Notify(QDialog, Ui_Notification):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.showAnim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
        self.showAnim.setDuration(700)
        self.showAnim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutBack)

        self.hideAnim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
        self.hideAnim.setDuration(700)
        self.hideAnim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutBack)

        self.hideTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True)
        self.hideTimer.setInterval(4000)

        self.hideTimer.timeout.connect(self.hideNote)
        self.showAnim.finished.connect(self.hideTimer.start)
        self.hideAnim.finished.connect(self.close)

    def setNote(self, icon=icon.checked, headline="Headline", text="Text"):
        self.icon = icon
        self.headline = headline
        self.text = text
        self.noty_Label_Icon.setText(self.icon)
        self.noty_Label_Headline.setText(self.headline)
        self.noty_Label_Text.setText(self.text)

        self.adjustSize() # important!
        endRect = self.rect()
        center = self.parent().geometry().center()
        endRect.moveCenter(center)
        screen = QApplication.screenAt(center)
        startRect = QRect(endRect)
        startRect.moveTop(screen.geometry().bottom())

        self.setGeometry(startRect)
        self.showAnim.setStartValue(startRect)
        self.showAnim.setEndValue(endRect)
        self.showAnim.start()
        self.show()

    def hideNote(self):
        rect = self.geometry()
        self.hideAnim.setStartValue(rect)
        screen = QApplication.screenAt(rect.center())
        rect.moveTop(screen.geometry().bottom())
        self.hideAnim.setEndValue(rect)
        self.hideAnim.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":     
    notes = QApplication(sys.argv)
    notes.setStyle('fusion')
    w = QMainWindow()
    b = QPushButton('click!')
    w.setCentralWidget(b)
    w.show()
    notify = Notify(w)
    b.clicked.connect(lambda: notify.setNote())
    sys.exit(notes.exec())
```

Be aware that if you're going to create the popup every time, you should also set the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute in order to destroy it when closed, otherwise it will be kept in memory.

<sup>Note: `QTimer.singleShot()` is a static function, creating an instance of QTimer to use it is pointless, as that instance won't be used and a *new* QTimer would be created anyway.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
In the meantime i found a solution which works for me.
Look a little dirty but works.
could you tell me, whats the difference between my code an yours?
Why should i use your code, except the fact that you are a better programmer ;-)
I set the `WA_DeleteOnClose` Attribute.
Good to know that. Thanks

**notes.py**

```
from UIs.UI_notify import Ui_Notification
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation, QTimer
import sys
class icon():
    checked = "check-circle"
    alert = "times-circle"
    question = "question-circle"
    clock = "clock"

class notify(QDialog, Ui_Notification):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(notify,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        self.Note_Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.parent_h = self.parent().geometry().height()
        self.parent_w = self.parent().geometry().width()
        self.parent_x = self.parent().geometry().x()
        self.parent_y = self.parent().geometry().y()
        self.dialog_w = self.width()
        self.dialog_h = self.height()   
        self.setGeometry(self.parent_x+self.parent_w-self.dialog_w-10, self.parent_y+self.parent_h-self.dialog_h+120, self.dialog_w, self.dialog_h)
        ## ScreenSize from parent
        ############################################################
    
    def setNote(self, icon=icon.checked, headline="Headline", text="Text"):
        self.icon = icon
        self.headline = headline
        self.text = text
        self.noty_Label_Icon.setText(self.icon)
        self.noty_Label_Headline.setText(self.headline)
        self.noty_Label_Text.setText(self.text)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self,b"geometry")
        self.anim.setDuration(700)
        self.anim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutBack)
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(self.parent_x+self.parent_w-self.dialog_w-10, self.parent_y+self.parent_h-self.dialog_h-20, self.dialog_w, self.dialog_h))
        self.anim.start()
        self.notyTimer = QTimer()
        self.notyTimer.singleShot(4000,self.hideNote)
    def hideNote(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self,b"geometry")
        self.anim.setDuration(700)
        self.anim.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutBack)
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(self.parent_x+self.parent_w-self.dialog_w-10, self.parent_y+self.parent_h-self.dialog_h+120, self.dialog_w, self.dialog_h))
        self.anim.start()
        self.anim.finished.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    notes = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = notify()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(notes.exec())
```